# How do you test/spoof a users geolocation in MVC.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, testing, geolocation

I'm working with a .NET team who have created a site that serves up different content based on a users location.

How would I go about testing/spoofing the geolocation so I can debug the front-end?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTML5 Location API to get user current location, then you can  debug it with Chrome. It supports overriding for current location - http://www.labnol.org/internet/geo-location/27878/ so you can specify any test coordinates

Also there is some extension for Firefox that allows to override it too.

Comment: I'm afraid they're not using HTML 5 Location API otherwise it would be much simpler. They are using some other method server-side to determine the location.

Comment: Well, then it will depend on the method that they are using. If you dont know for sure - it will be hard to test it. Typical way is try to determine -user IP address and then understand country by IP. In that case you can try to find some anonymizer\proxy to connect to that app via them.

Answer (score 0):

I have server side validation and faking it via google chrome [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj) by changing CountryCode header, or X-Forwarder For header, depends on the settings.